# Is it possible to place an image in Tkinter without a Label or canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to place images next to each other side by side but the labels overlap and the label sticks out.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x700")
root.resizable(0, 0)
##############################################
TFi = PhotoImage(file="images/Topframe.png")
TF = Label(root, image=TFi)
TF.place(x=-3, y=-3)
BFi = PhotoImage(file="images/Botframe.png")
BF = Label(root, image=BFi)
BF.place(x=-3, y=650)
LF1i = PhotoImage(file="images/LeftFrame1.png")
LF1 = Label(root, image=LF1i)
LF1.place(x=-3, y=50)
##############################################
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "label sticks out"? Generally, `grid` and `pack` are going to be easier to work with for placing objects compared to `place`. These two methods will prevent objects from overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to place an image in Tkinter without a Label or canvas

Your most common choices for labels are a canvas or a label. You can also put images on buttons, and embed them in a text widget.

The best choice for creating labels that are next to each other are to use `pack` or `grid`. `pack` is good if you're making a single horizontal or vertical grouping, but `grid` is better if you're making both rows and columns of widgets.

You can use `place`, but that requires that you do all of the math to compute the location of each image, and usually results in a user interface that isn't very resilient to changes in screen resolution. It also sometimes ends up causing you to have to do changes to every widget even if you only want to tweak the layout slightly.

My guess for why they overlap is that you aren't aware that the coordinates you give `place` by default specify the center of the image rather than the upper-left corner. You can specify which part of the image is at the given coordinate with the `anchor` option.

> the label sticks out.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that, but if you mean that it has a 3D appearance, you can control that by giving it a `borderwidth` of zero and/or a `relief` of `"flat"`.